# Docker containers retaining data

Tags: docker, dockerfile, lamp

I'm learning Docker and I've been crafting a Dockerfile for an Ubuntu container.

My problem is I keep getting persistent information between different containers. I have exited, removed the container and then removed its image. After I made changes to my Dockerfile, I executed `docker build -t playbuntu .` Executing the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

    ## for apt to be noninteractive
    ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
    ENV DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN true

    ## preesed tzdata, update package index, upgrade packages and install needed software
    RUN echo "tzdata tzdata/Areas select Europe" > /tmp/preseed.txt; \
        echo "tzdata tzdata/Zones/Europe select London" >> /tmp/preseed.txt; \
        debconf-set-selections /tmp/preseed.txt && \
        apt-get update && \
        apt-get install -y tzdata


    RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install tree nano vim -y && apt-get install less -y && apt-get install lamp-server^ -y

    RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

    EXPOSE 80

    WORKDIR /var/www

    COPY ./index.php /var/www
    COPY ./000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available

    CMD [ "apache2ctl", "start", "&&", "apache2ctl", "restart" ]
```

Once I execute `winpty docker run -it -p 80:80 playbuntu bash`, my problem is, instead of my index.php file outputting the following:

```
<?php

    print "<center><h3>Sisko's LAMP activated!</h3><center>";

    phpinfo();
```

I get the following debug code I experimented with hours ago:

```
<?php

    print "...responding";

    phpinfo();
```

Is there a caching system Docker might be using? I pruned all Docker volumes just in case that is how Docker might be caching. All except 2 volumes which are being used by other containers unrelated to my project.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that, after you changed `index.php` on your host machine you did **not** rerun the `docker build ...` command. You will need to recreate the container image any time any of the image's content changes.

Please confirm whether running the `docker build ...` command again solves the issue.

#### Background

Docker images comprise one of more layers.

Image (layers) and Volumes are distinct.

Since your `docker run ...` command contains no e.g. `--volume=` bind mounts (or equivalent), I suspect Docker Volumes are not relevant to this question.

There is a possibility that rebuilding images does **not** replace image layers and thus caching does occur. However, in your case, I think this is **not** the issue. See the Docker documentation ([link](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/)) for an overview of the Dockerfile commands that add layers.

Because of the way that layers work, if the *preceding* layers in your Dockerfile were unchanged **and** the `index.php` were unchanged, then Docker would not rebuild these layers. However, because your Dockerfile includes a layer that `apt-get update && apt-get install ....`, the layer will be invalidated, recreated and so will subsequent layers.

If you change `index.php` on the host and rebuild the image, this layer will **always** be rebuilt.

I built your Dockerfile twice. Here's the beginning of the second (!) build command. NB the `Using cache` commands for the unchanged layers preceding the `RUN apt-get update...` layer which is rebuilt.

```sh
docker build --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t 59582820:0939 "."
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB
Step 1/10 : FROM ubuntu:latest
 ---> 549b9b86cb8d
Step 2/10 : ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1529d0e293f3
Step 3/10 : ENV DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN true
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1ba10410d06a
Step 4/10 : RUN echo "tzdata tzdata/Areas select Europe" > /tmp/preseed.txt;     echo "tzdata tzdata/Zones/Europe select London" >> /tmp/preseed.txt;     debconf-set-selections /tmp/preseed.txt &&     apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y tzdata
 ---> Using cache
 ---> afb861da52e4
Step 5/10 : RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install tree nano vim -y && apt-get install less -y && apt-get install lamp-server^ -y
 ---> Running in 6f05bbb8e80a
```

The evidence suggests to me that you didn't rebuild after changing the index.php.

Comment: Thanks. I'm running it again but I am absolutely certain I removed my ubuntu image and executed docker build each time. Plus, initially I was trying to create a connection to allow me to edit the container files from Windows. That wasn't working

Comment: So, this is a strange result. Despite my assertions that I had been rebuilding the image all along, this time I got the correct content in index.php. However, I exited and removed that container and created a second container from the same image. The only difference this time was I added -v c:/localfile-system:/var/www to experiment with editing container code from windows. And now, index.php is show the debug code again

Comment: So... There's also a difference between Docker Image(s) and Container(s). When an image is run, it creates a Container. Multiple Containers may be created from the same Image. I think your issue is that you had not rebuilt the Image and so any Containers created from it, used the original `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use volumes to persist some folders like configs or properties etc. [Docker Storage](https://docs.docker.com/storage/)